# Declaration of variables improve or decrease performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, execution

So I am trying to improve my SQL, one topic that arose, does declaration help with performance or not so like for instance lets say you want to do a if else statement but you need to know if the count is higher than 0 for example right

```
SELECT @COUNTER = COUNT(ID) FROM tblSome WHERE NUMBER > TOTAL

IF(@COUNTER > 0)
```

OR would it be better than something like this

```
IF((SELECT @COUNTER = COUNT(ID) FROM tblSome WHERE NUMBER > TOTAL)>0)
```

I am just trying to minimize the time it takes, but also it would be nice to know

For now I cannot really find a difference with the small amounts of data I am using and I am not sure how to test it further or go test it to the next level

Comment: Performance troubleshooting is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s added it on, I am using sql-server

Comment: Your second query isn't valid syntax in SQL Server, so that is out the window. If you are only ever using `@counter` to determine if any rows are present, then I would say the best way is to use `EXISTS`, i.e. `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblSome WHERE Number > Total)...`, although realistically SQL Server would also likely create the same plan for `IF((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tblSome WHERE NUMBER > TOTAL)>0)` I'd say why take the chance - To measure though, the best thing for you to do here is [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Word of warning. There are few, if any, *absolute* rules about performance. And in the vast majority of cases, writing clear, readable code will produce results which are *good enough*. Don't think you can learn (a thousand, a million, a billion) rules for performance and just blindly apply them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of variables can help or hinder performance dependent on the exact circumstances. There isn't a single rule.

In this case the use of the separate variable assignment step can be harmful.

It gives the optimiser no choice but to count all the rows as it doesn't look ahead to how you use that variable in future statements.

using an `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) > 0` allows the optimiser to see that it is `true` as long as the count is `>=1` and can sometimes be optimised to an `IF EXISTS` (semi join) and stop reading after a single row.

But you are better off just writing it as `EXISTS` anyway rather than relying on that.

(The discussion on [this internet archived blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809110631/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx) has more about the circumstances where this optimisation might happen)